# NHibernate does not throw exception when calling Session.Save on persisted entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm writing a test case to ensure my service/repository layers work as expected. I am calling `ISession.Save` and with an entity which has already been persisted to the database in a separate transaction. I expect `Save` to throw an exception because the entity is not new. Instead, a new entry is added to the DB and the entity's ID is updated.

First question: is this expected? As far as I can tell it should throw an exception, but I haven't been able to find that explicitly in [NHibernate documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html).

Some code:

```
public class Dashboard 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

// Dashboard.hbm.xml:
<class name="Dashboard" table="Dashboard" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="ID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
</class>

Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
using(var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Session.Save(dashboard);
    transaction.Commit();
}

Session.Flush();

using(var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Session.Save(dashboard);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

My understanding is that the above code should throw an exception. Is this correct?

Comment: can't tell if it should throw an exception, but afaik you should use SaveOrUpdate 99% of the time.. lurking here hoping someone can give a decent explanation

Comment: I disagree. I don't like leaving whether a Save or Update occurs to NHibernate. We already know whether a Save or Update is necessary based on which API endpoint was reached. It would seem incorrect to then allow for ambiguity in the repository layer.

Comment: Your code should ensure consistency, I wouldn't trust a data layer constraint ever. Do the checks yourself and avoid current and future bugs in the framework and/or your actual storage.

Comment: Aren't we saying the same thing then? That you shouldn't rely on SaveOrUpdate? :p

Comment: I tried this in my existing installation. My entity object uses a `Nullable<long>` as the key, not a `long`. Saving it a second time did not throw an exception, but it also did not add the object a second time. What happens if you add an `unsaved-value`attributes to your `id` element in the mapping file?

Comment: I feel this as a "work as intended" case. Such design choices in NHibernate are usually inherited from Hibernate, maybe should you search for more insights on this on Hibernate side.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I did try adding `unsaved-value` but it had no effect (docs implied it would not have an effect). I didn't verify the DB had a new entry, though, either.. only that the in memory object had a new ID. It's not a huge issue and is something I can handle myself with a simple check.. just was surprised NHibernate wouldn't throw in this scenario. Thanks for checking :)

Answer (score 0):

I've opted to handle this manually by throwing an exception myself.

Something like:

```
public void Save(T entity)
{
    if (entity.ID != 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempted to save an entity which has already been saved.");

    Session.Save(entity);
}
```